# Mudar Conteúdo dentro de um modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Como posso carregar um modal e nesse modal ter um botão que ao clicar troca o conteúdo por outra pagina desse modal que já está aberto, e que ao fechar volte para o conteúdo anterior. Estou usando o framework front-end materialize.

Estou tendo problemas para elaborar o js em que mude o conteúdo do modal inicial por outra pagina, consigo mudar o conteúdo por um texto, mas não abrir outra pagina dentro dele.

Comment: O único jeito de mostrar conteúdo de outra página no modal é com um iframe. E isso se o outro site permitir que seu conteúdo seja renderizado em um iframe.

Comment: está faltando informação na sua pergunta. Qual modal você está usando?  jQuery Dialog? Ou é uma modal Javascript? Coloque o seu código pra ficar mais fácil. Quando você diz *outra página*  está falando de outra url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

É preciso carregar os dados dinamicamente na mesma página ou a partir de outra. Não requer uso de iframe. Mas será carregado o html da página, ou até mesmo de uma div ou outra tag especifica usando um jQuery bem simples (requer conhecimento básico). Mas isso também é possível usando angular (requer conhecimento intermediário).

Em jQuery eu uso este código para isso:

```
$('#MytargetDiv').load('https://www.example.org/anyPage.html #MytargetContent', function() {
// escreva suas funções ou ações aqui
// você pode alterar, ocultar ou exibir o conteúdo recebido como no exemplo abaixo
$('p.summary').hide(); // ou
$('div img.thumb').remove(); // se o carregamento for bem sucedido estas funções ou ações serão executadas. isso permite infinitas possibilidades.
});
```

Se você precisa ou quer usar o conteúdo completo pode utilizar desta forma.

```
$('.Class4TargetDiv').load('https://www.example.org #TargetDivWithContent');
```

ou

```
$('#MyTargetDiv').load('https://www.example.org .TargetDivWithContent');
```

Lembrando que para identificar o elemento que deseja carregar pode identifica-lo por Id (#elementid) ou por uma classe CSS (.anyclass).

Obs.: Você deve aplicar ou chamar este código no evento do link ou do botão que usará para acionar a alteração de conteúdo.

Espero que seja útil.